# ERROR Error: Cannot find module '@xtuc/long'

Tags: vue.js

I am learning vueJs, I have installed my project using CLI and by project has successfully installed, the problem come when i need to run my project via terminal with a command npm run serve, below is the error that occur after running the command

$ npm run serve

```
  > school@0.1.0 serve C:\Users\Mr chomvu\Documents\vueproject\school
  > vue-cli-service serve

  INFO  Starting development server...
  ERROR  Error: Cannot find module '@xtuc/long'
  Error: Cannot find module '@xtuc/long'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
  (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:582:15)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:25)
  at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
  at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
  at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Mr 
  chomvu\Documents\vueproject\school\node_modules\@webassemblyjs\wast- 
  printer\lib\index.js:10:36)
  at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js 
  (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
  at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
  at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 1
  npm ERR! school@0.1.0 serve: `vue-cli-service serve`
  npm ERR! Exit status 1
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the school@0.1.0 serve script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely 
  additional logging output above.

  npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
  npm ERR!     C:\Users\Mr chomvu\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019- 
  06-08T13_11_37_227Z-debug.log


  I do expect after successfully compilation to have a local: 
  https://localhost:8080
```

I have attached the error image:
[image: img]

Comment: You can try remove the node_modules directory `rm -rf node_modules` and reinstall all modules by `npm install`

Comment: I have tried to remove node module as you recommend   and install again but still I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you don't make any changes in project, just you trying to install and run your first vue.js app then follow this guide [Creating a Project CLI](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/creating-a-project.html#using-the-gui), and everything will be fine.
Be sure you using the latest version of node & npm.

If you want to fix this project try remove `node_modules` and the `package-lock.json` file, and than run `npm install`